# Duda formulario JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, email, html-correo

estoy realizando un formulario, estoy utilizando PHP y JavaScript para las validaciones, mi duda es que puedo hacer para que después de enviar el correo me limpie los campos de nuevo, espero me puedan auxiliar.

Mi código HTML y PHP:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validarContactenos()">
                                            
<input type="text" id="nombreContactenos" name="nombreContactenos" placeholder="Escriba su nombre" required>  
                              
<input type="email" id="emailContactenos" name="emailContactenos" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Escriba su correo electrónico" required>  
                                              
<textarea id="mensajeContactenos"  name="mensajeContactenos" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" rows="5" required></textarea>  
                        
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">                  

  <?php

    $contactenos = new ControladorPlantilla();
    $contactenos -> ctrFormularioContactenos();

  ?>
</form>
```

Mi código PHP y alertas Java Script:

```
    public function ctrFormularioContactenos(){

        if(isset($_POST["mensajeContactenos"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nombreContactenos"]) &&
             preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["emailContactenos"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[?\\¿\\!\\¡\\:\\,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["mensajeContactenos"])
             ){

                /*=============================================
                ENVÍO CORREO ELECTRÓNICO CON PHP MAILER
                =============================================*/

                date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

                $mail->isMail();

                $mail->setFrom('micorreo@midominio.com', 'Nombre de la empresa');

                $mail->addReplyTo($_POST["emailContactenos"], $_POST["nombreContactenos"]);

                $mail->Subject = "Ha recibido una consulta";

                $mail->addAddress("micorreo@midominio.com");

                $mail->msgHTML('Aqui coloque código html, es mucho y por eso no lo puse pero si 
                                funciona');

                $envio = $mail->Send();

                if(!$envio){

                    echo '<script> 

                            swal({
                                    type:"error",
                                    title: "¡ERROR!",
                                    text: "¡Ha ocurrido un problema enviando el mensaje!",                           
                                    showConfirmButton: true,
                                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                                
                                }).then(function(result){

                                    if(result.value){
                                        history.back();
                                    }
                            });

                        </script>';


                }else{

                    echo '<script> 

                            swal({
                                    type: "success",
                                    title: "¡OK!",
                                    text: "¡Su mensaje ha sido enviado, muy pronto le responderemos!",                   
                                    showConfirmButton: true,
                                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                                
                                }).then(function(result){

                                    if(result.value){
                                        history.back();
                                    }
                            });


                        </script>';

                }


            }else{

                echo '<script>

                    swal({
                            type:"error",
                            title: "¡ERROR!",
                            text: "¡Problemas al enviar el mensaje, revise que no tenga caracteres especiales!",
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                        
                        }).then(function(result){

                            if(result.value){
                                history.back();
                            }
                    });

                </script>';

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Código JavaScript

```
$("#nombreContactenos").val("");
$("#emailContactenos").val("");
$("#mensajeContactenos").val("");

function validarContactenos() {

    $(".alert").remove();

    var nombre = $("#nombreContactenos").val();
    var email = $("#emailContactenos").val();
    var mensaje = $("#mensajeContactenos").val();

    /*=============================================
    VALIDACIÓN DEL NOMBRE
    =============================================*/

    if (nombre == "") {

        $("#nombreContactenos").before('<h6 class="alert alert-danger">Escriba 
        por favor el nombre</h6>');

        return false;

    } else {

        var expresion = /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;

        if (!expresion.test(nombre)) {

            $("#nombreContactenos").before('<h6 class="alert alert-danger">Escriba por favor sólo letras sin caracteres especiales</h6>');

            return false;

        }

    }

Y así sucesivamente para correo y mensaje, con sus diferentes expresiones regulares, las cuales también funcionan
```

Si envía los correos, pero al momento de que aparece el mensaje de que fue exitoso veo que el formulario aún tiene los datos que puse en el formulario, espero me puedan auxiliar, ya que no sé como arreglarlo

Muchas gracias de antemano, que pasen excelente tarde. =)

Comment: Si quieres limpiar los campos de un formulario, crearía una función tipo `cleanFormFields()` y ahí setearía su valor a cadena vacía. Ya haces algo parecido al recoger el valor del campo (get)... simplemente, si te he entendido bien, te faltaría hacer el set de cadena vacía.

Comment: Para limpiar el formulario, puedes agregarle un ID al formulario y usa esto dentro de tu success de tu función : $("#formEjemplo")[0].reset(); y asi limpiaras el formulario

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugiero limpiar los campos (`inputs`) una vez pase las validaciones y se guarde los datos en las variables correspondientes.

- Validaciones de los datos
- Guardar los datos validos
- Limpiar campos (inputs)

  ```js
  $("#nombreContactenos").val(""); //Limpiar
  $("#emailContactenos").val(""); //Limpiar
  $("#mensajeContactenos").val(""); //Limpiar
  ```
- Enviar datos al servidor